# Broadcom bcm4318 airforce one 54g, can't connect to WiFi

Tags: wireless, networking

Yesterday I finally installed Ubuntu on my old, hacked Fujitsu Siemens Amilo A1650 laptop (Running Windows XP Home Edition).

It runs fine but I can`t find my WiFi connection!

I tried solutions I found online but they didn't work for me. It could be because the network is unstable here (I have a mobile Broadband and a WiFi connection)

My network card is  "broadcom bcm4318 airforce one 54g". I can't use a Ethernet cable on my modem because it doesn't have a port to do it.

Comment: So let me understand, right now, you can use the mobile broadband, you are only having problems with the WiFi, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's frustrating. Especially here where instead of getting answers you get more questions. Anyway, see below for what worked for me. I had the same problem. The LAST option is what worked for me. I tried about 50 different methods to get the g-d wifi working, and finally did using the below: Make sure you do the update and upgrade before though. I did not write this, this was taken from another part of this forum.

You can fix wifi problems using two methods:

Either connect to the internet via wired connection and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot your system.

Or use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux linux-headers-generic kernel-package
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl* firmware-b43-lpphy-installer b43-fwcutter
```

Finally, reboot your system.

If that didn't help, try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
sudo reboot
```

Comment: You had the same problem with the same network card? The reason we ask questions of users with wireless issues is that they are generally hardware-specific. If you took parts of your answer from elsewhere, please give attribution.